# What can I break and how long does it take to break it?

Tags: rust

There are various structures in the game, walls, doors, doorways, stairs, ramps, ceilings, pillars, foundations that can be made out of wood or metal.

What can I break with my hatchet/pickaxe and how long does it take?

What can I blow up with grenades or c4 and how many does it take?

Comment: @downvoter: Why the downvote?  This question is highly relevant to securing your base in the game, but the answer for different items is scattered across the internet, and for some can't seem to be found at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an accurate list of things you can destroy and the effort you need.
I didn't tried personally to destroy all the things listed, but many that I tried confirm those numbers.

Pratically is important to remember that you can destroy all except pillars, ceilings and foundations.

Credits to user *Juper0* / [Source](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Juper0/Breaking_things_list)

#### Wood

```
Wood Shelter: 400 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 167 Hits - Pickaxe, 11-12 - Grenades, 1-2 Charges - C4
Wood Wall: 11-12 - Grenades, 2 - Charges C4
Wood Pillar: Only by decay
Wood Stairs: 54 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 23 Hits - Pickaxe, 11 - Grenades, 1 Charge - C4
Wood Ramp: 84 Hits - Pickaxe, 10 - Grenades, 1 Charge - C4
Wood Ceiling: Only by decay
Wood Foundation: Only by decay
Wood Window: 11-12 - Grenades, 1 Charge
Wood Window w/ Bars: 2 Charges - C4
Wood Doorway: 11-12 - Grenades, 1-2 Charges - C4
Wood Doorway w/Door Attached: 2 Charges - C4
Wood Door: 200 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 84 Hits - Pickaxe, 6 - Grenades, 1 Charge - C4
Wood Gateway: 5 Charges - C4
Wood Gate: 120 Hits - Pickaxe, 32 - Grenades, 3 Charges - C4
```

#### Metal

```
Metal Wall: 4 Charges - C4
Metal Pillar: Only by decay
Metal Stairs: 1 Charge - C4
Metal Ramp: 1 Charge - C4
Metal Ceiling: Only by decay
Metal Foundation: Only by decay
Metal Window: 3 Charges - C4
Metal Window w/Bars: 3 Charges - C4
Metal Doorway: 2 Charges - C4
Metal Doorway w/Door Attached: 3 Charges - C4
Metal Door: 11 - Grenades, 2 Charges - C4 (Metal Doors cannot be damaged by melee weapons or guns. Only through explosives.)
```

#### Objects

```
Wood Barricade: 17 Hits - Pickaxe, 2 Charges - C4
Spike Wall: 25 Hits - Pickaxe, 1 Charge - C4
Large Spike Wall: 100 Hits - Pickaxe, 2 Charges - C4
Small Stash: 5 Hits - Rock, 7 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 4 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 2 Hits - Pickaxe
Small Wood Storage Box: 34 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 20 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 9 Hits - Pickaxe, 1 Charge - C4
Large Wood Storage Box: 67 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 40 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 17 Hits - Pickaxe, 3 Charges - C4
Furnace: 34 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 20 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 9 Hits - Pickaxe, 2 Charges - C4
Workbench: 67 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 40 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 17 Hits - Pickaxe, 3 Charges - C4
Camp Fire: 34 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 20 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 9 Hits - Pickaxe, 1 Charge - C4
Sleeping Bag: 34 Hits - Stone Hatchet, 20 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 9 Hits - Pickaxe, 1 Charge - C4
```

Comment: i just testet it on our metal ramp and it needed 2 charges of c4.

Comment: @Gigala You are right, also Wood Walls now requires consistently 2xC4 charges.

Comment: The flamethrower can burn wood, this could also be mentionned.

Answer (score 1):

The playrust wiki (http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/List_of_things_to_Craft) lists all the items and what can be broke on every individual page from that list. For example, for the wood door :

> Wood Doors are destructable - they can be taken down when it has been hit 200 times with a rock or 80 times with a pick axe.

The wiki will also tell if sometimes item can't be destroyed. However, they might despawn under certain conditions.

Comment: Great answer on hard to find material. Not sure why the downvotes on this answer.

Comment: Actually I edited my answer because it was getting downvotes. Truth be said, the first one was lacking details and kinda deserved it.

Comment: This answer is still massively incomplete to the point that I can't even consider it an answer; this should just be a comment.

Comment: Is there a point to copy/paste huge amount of data from another wiki, especially when this information is subject to change as the game is in an early alpha stage ? This will lead to outdated informations here, hence hurting the quality of the answers.

Comment: There **is** a point in aggregating and summarizing it in one, easy to find place, yes.  That's literally the whole reason this site exists.